# Conjugacy classes cointened each other

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, representation-theory

Take $G=GL(n)$ which acts on $M_n$ for conjugation. Take $A$ and $B$ two orbits so they are two conjugacy classes. I was reading notes where I found "A contained in B but not the same subset". It's this possible? The action should induce an equivalence relation on $M_{n}$ and so they are the same or the intersection, like subset, is empty. I am right?

Answer (score 0):

The term conjugacy class is reserved for a group acting on itself by inner automorphism.  Here you are discussing action of the group of non-singular matrices on "all matrices". So *orbit* would be the right terminology here.

For all group actions orbits of two different elements are either identical or disjoint (cosets of a subgroup is the first case one encounters for this result).

Here is my attempt at a possible way of explaining what you say. When a group $G$ acts on aset $X$ then every subgroup $H$ of $G$ also acts on the same set. So one can have a finer notion of $G$-orbits and $H$-orbits.

$\{g.x\mid g \in G\}$ is the $G$-orbit of $x\in X$.

$\{h.x\mid h \in H\}$ is the $H$-orbit of $x\in X$.

Clearly $H$-orbit is a subset of the $G$ orbit of the same $x$. it can happen that they are equal.